# sem_open for the array POSIX

Tags: c, unix, posix, semaphore

I would like to open n semaphores (n from argv[]). 
I did array of sem_t* and I try to sem_open them in a loop. However, I need const char* unique name for each semaphore. 
Is there any way to do it? Help, please :)

```
sem_t *sem[n];
int i;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
sem[i] = my_sem_open("XXXXXX",0);
```

Comment: I think your problem would benefit from using sem_init instead of sem_open.

Comment: But the other issue seems to be that you're confused about what it means for a function to take a `const char *` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is very brief illustration of idea how to get unique semaphore names. In real system there could be some wrappers around semaphore creation / deletion with array of free ID. Every operation could take ID from this array (on sem_open()) or free one of them (sem_close()).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 10

int next_sema_id()
{
    static int seq_number = 0;
    return seq_number++;
}

int main()
{
    int n = N;

    sem_t *sem[n];
    int i;

    pid_t pid = getpid();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char buf[12];
        sprintf(buf, "sem%05d%03d", pid, next_sema_id());
        sem[i] = sem_open(buf,0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sem_close(sem[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*This would be a comment to [Roman Nikitchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204665/roman-nikitchenko)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15576313/15168) except that the quote from the POSIX standard is too long to fit into a single comment.*

Note what POSIX says about the path to [`sem_open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html):

> The name argument points to a string naming a semaphore object. It is unspecified whether the name appears in the file system and is visible to functions that take pathnames as arguments. The name argument conforms to the construction rules for a pathname, except that the interpretation of `<slash>` characters other than the leading `<slash>` character in name is implementation-defined, and that the length limits for the name argument are implementation-defined and need not be the same as the pathname limits {PATH_MAX} and {NAME_MAX}. If name begins with the `<slash>` character, then processes calling `sem_open()` with the same value of name shall refer to the same semaphore object, as long as that name has not been removed. If name does not begin with the `<slash>` character, the effect is implementation-defined.

I think this says that the portable semaphore names are of the form `/some-unique-name-without-slashes`, where the maximum length is not clearly defined.  Other names (without a leading slash, or with extra slashes) may or may not work — you need to read the manual for the implementation you're using (the implementation must define what's allowed).