# How to unlink/close an array of named semaphores in C

Tags: arrays, c, posix, semaphore

I am trying to create an array of N named POSIX semaphores in C. But I am having trouble unlinking and closing them. I need to use an array of semaphores because each semaphore will represent a segment of a text file that will later go into shared memory.

I am doing something very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575510/sem-open-for-the-array-posix) post but it is not working. Maybe the problem is in the creation of the semaphores? Is there another way I could do this?

```
sem_t* semaphores[N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "s%d", i);       // Give a unique name to each semaphore
    semaphores[i] = sem_open(buf, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, SEM_PERMS, INITIAL_VALUE);
}

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    if(sem_unlink((void*)semaphores[i]) < 0){
        perror("sem_unlink(0) failed OVER HERE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 }

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    if(sem_close(semaphores[i]) < 0){
        perror("sem_close(0) failed HERE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 }
```

The error message I am getting is:

> sem_unlink(0) failed OVER HERE: No such file or directory

Comment: Given `int sem_unlink(const char *name);` and `sem_t* semaphores[N];`, `sem_unlink((void*)semaphores[i])` is wrong.  The `void *` cast is a dead giveaway you did something wrong.  You can't cast away errors like that.

Comment: `sem_unlink(const char *name)` takes the name of the semaphore, not a pointer to it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle noted, this was just me debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`sem_close(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_close.3.html) takes a `sem_t *` argument, [`sem_unlink(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_unlink.3.html) takes the name of the semaphore as a `const char *`.

Retain the names of your semaphores, so that they may be passed to [`sem_unlink(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_unlink.3.html) later. The example below uses an array of structures to do so.

Additionally, per [`sem_overview(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), semaphore names should begin with a leading `/`.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INITIAL_VALUE 1
#define N 8
#define SEM_PERMS 0666

int main(void)
{
    struct {
        char name[128];
        sem_t *sem;
    } semaphores[N];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sprintf(semaphores[i].name, "/a-semaphore%zu", i);
        semaphores[i].sem = sem_open(semaphores[i].name,
                O_CREAT | O_EXCL, SEM_PERMS, INITIAL_VALUE);

        if (SEM_FAILED == semaphores[i].sem)
            perror(semaphores[i].name);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (sem_unlink(semaphores[i].name) < 0)
            perror(semaphores[i].name);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (sem_close(semaphores[i].sem) < 0)
            perror(semaphores[i].name);
}
```

---

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) points out below, storing each name is not necessarily required. Since the names are algorithmically generated, you could regenerate them from the same template when they are needed again.

A cursory example:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INITIAL_VALUE 1
#define N 8
#define SEM_PERMS 0666

void namegen(char *dst, size_t suffix)
{
    sprintf(dst, "/a-semaphore%zu", suffix);
}

int main(void)
{
    sem_t *semaphores[N];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        char name[128];
        namegen(name, i);

        semaphores[i] = sem_open(name,
                O_CREAT | O_EXCL, SEM_PERMS, INITIAL_VALUE);

        if (SEM_FAILED == semaphores[i])
            perror(name);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        char name[128];
        namegen(name, i);

        if (sem_unlink(name) < 0)
            perror(name);

        if (sem_close(semaphores[i]) < 0)
            perror(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, since the semaphore names are algorithmically generated, the same names could be regenerated from the original data (name template and number of names to generate, in this case).  The generated names themselves don't necessarily need to be retained.